# jq filter for only 'null' values

Tags: linux, aws, json, jq

I have a json file with a load of AWS CloudWatch logs (generated from a CLI command). I'm trying to use jq to **only** return values for entries that don't have a 'retentionInDays' field. I have the following which returns everything as I want, but I can't seem to filter out the results that do have retentionInDays.

```
# Working output (unfiltered)
jq ".logGroups[] | { log_name: .logGroupName, log_arn: .arn, retention_scheme: .retentionInDays }" cwlogs.json
```

I've tried a couple of things, but either get an error, or it completes and outputs nothing:

```
# Doesn't return anything
jq '.logGroups[] | { log_name: .logGroupName, log_arn: .arn, retention_scheme: select(.retentionInDays | contains ("null")?) }' cwlogs.json

# Errors with "jq: error (at cwlogs.json:760): number (7) and string ("null") cannot have their containment checked"
jq '.logGroups[] | { log_name: .logGroupName, log_arn: .arn, retention_scheme: select(.retentionInDays | contains ("null")) }' cwlogs.json

# Hangs forever
jq '.logGroups[] | select(.retentionInDays != "null").type'
```

Update:
Testable segment of JSON I'm using

```
{
    "logGroups": [
        {
            "storedBytes": 0,
            "metricFilterCount": 0,
            "creationTime": 1234,
            "logGroupName": "/aws/elasticbeanstalk/docker",
            "retentionInDays": 7,
            "arn": "longarnhere"
        },
        {
            "storedBytes": 0,
            "metricFilterCount": 0,
            "creationTime": 1245,
            "logGroupName": "/aws/elasticbeanstalk/nginx",
            "arn": "longarnhere"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: post a testable fragment

Comment: Are you talking about extracting records that don't have a specific field, or records that has a `null` value for an _existing_ field?  The title and the text in the question are contradictory on this point.  Also, by "filter out", do you mean "extract" or "discard"?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'm assuming you want to get the `logGroups` entries that don't have a `retentionInDays` key at all.

```
$ jq '.logGroups[] | select( has("retentionInDays") == false )' file.json
{
  "storedBytes": 0,
  "metricFilterCount": 0,
  "creationTime": 1245,
  "logGroupName": "/aws/elasticbeanstalk/nginx",
  "arn": "longarnhere"
}
```

If you want an array of these (likely, if there may be more than one):

```
$ jq '.logGroups | map(select( has("retentionInDays") == false ))' file.json
[
  {
    "storedBytes": 0,
    "metricFilterCount": 0,
    "creationTime": 1245,
    "logGroupName": "/aws/elasticbeanstalk/nginx",
    "arn": "longarnhere"
  }
]
```

You could also use `has("retentionInDays") | not` in place of `has("retentionInDays") == false`.

Answer (score 8):

You can use the alternative operator : `//` .

For example:

```bsh
echo '{"a" : "b"}' | jq '. | .c // "Null"'
```

Or in your example filtering can be done by adding `type` too to the filter:

```bsh
jq '.logGroups[] | select (.retentionInDays.type != null)'
```

Comment: I've tried your example but I get `jq: error (at cwlogs.json:760): Cannot index number with string "type"`

Comment: could you post an example json so that we see what we need to parse? or if it''s too big, just minimize it to the part we need

Comment: I get the same error as @Mcar49; this can be fixed for me by removing the reference to type and just saying `jq '.logGroups[] | select (.retentionInDays != null)'`